# Passing an AudioBuffer to LibGdx FFT

Tags: java, audio, fft, libgdx, audiobuffer

I have a problem with LibGdx, i whish to make an audio visualizer for Android using libGdx, i could use the Android FFt from the Visualizer class() but, since i want my app to work on Desktop to, i can't.

What i want is to finaly be able to make this :

```
for(int i=0; i < fft.getBandWidth(); i++){
    pixmap.drawLine(0, 480, 1600, (int) fft.getBand(i));
}
```

A frequency wave for now, if i can make this i can use the fft the way i know how.
I use this methods because i have first learned with processing and Minim Audio work this way.

For now, i have :

> ```
>       Assets.playMusic(Assets.music);
>       float[] samples = new float[SAMPLES];
>       ShortBuffer shortSamples = AudioTools.allocateShortBuffer(SAMPLES, 1);
>       fft.forward(samples);
>       pixmap.setColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
>       for(int i = 0; i < fft.getBandWidth(); i++)
>       {
>           pixmap.drawLine(0, 480, 1600, (int) fft.getBand(i));
>       }
> ```

I hope i am understundable (french in first language). And thank all of you who are willing to answer my question.